# pass in multiple arguments in lettuce test step

Tags: python, testing, lettuce

generally each lettuce test step takes 1 parameter, is there a way to pass in multiple arguments in a single step ?

like, can I have this:

```
@step('I have the number (\d+) and character (\w+)')
def have_the_number(step, number, character ):
    world.number = int(number)
    world.character = str(character)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid. You can both positional arguments (like `*args`, just like in your example) as well as named ones (like `**kwargs`).

Consider you have the following `math.feature`:

```
Feature: Basic computations
    In order to play with Lettuce
    As beginners
    We will implement addition and subtraction

    Scenario: Sum of 0 and 1
        Given I have to add the numbers 0 and 1
        When I compute its factorial
        Then I see the number 1

    Scenario: Difference of 3 and 5
        Given I have to substract 5 from 3
        When I compute their difference
        Then I see the number -2
```

and such `steps.py`:

```
from lettuce import *

@step('I have to add the numbers (\d+) and (\d+)')
def have_to_add(step, number1, number2):
    world.number1 = int(number1)
    world.number2 = int(number2)

@step('I have to substract (?P<subtrahend>) from (?P<minuend>)')
def have_to_substract(step, minuend, subtrahend):
    world.minuend = int(minuend)
    world.subtrahend = int(subtrahend)

@step('I compute their difference')
def compute_difference(step):
    world.number = world.minuend - world.subtrahend

@step('I compute their sum')
def compute_sum(step):
    world.number = world.number1 + world.number2

@step('I see the number (\d+)')
def check_number(step, expected):
    expected = int(expected)
    assert world.number == expected, "Got %d" % world.number
```

Take a closer look at the subtraction example, it shows how you can refer to captured variables by name rather then by position.

Answer (score 1):

What prevent you from doing that ? 
You ***can*** use multiple arguments in a single step just like your example shows.

I guess the step name is just parsed as a regular expression pattern, the matched groups will be passed in the step handler as parameters.

Comment: just not sure, as no example is using it this way, is there a documentation item linking to this usage ? anyways I will verify.

Comment: I use this all the way in my projects. What problem are you facing that make you believe it will not work ?

Comment: no problem, just no one in my project use it like this, ok confirmed then.